Data category visibility on PermissionSet
Is there a way to programatically fetch or deploy the Data Category Group Visiblities on PermissionSet via the metadata api?
I see in this documentation that PermissionSetCategoryGroupVisibility isnt mentioned - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm

Look like only Profiles support this. See Idea

Be worth joining the Future of User Management trailblazer group to get this to the attention of the PM
